# How to make and draw a Perlin Noise on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to make a application that draws a noise to a JPanel in Java. I came up with a really random noise, but i would like to draw a Perlin or Simplex Noise.
Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint extends JPanel {

private static boolean running = false;
private static Paint paint = new Paint();
private static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    running = true;
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(800, 800);
    f.setResizable(running);
    f.setUndecorated(running);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.add(paint);
    f.setVisible(running);

    while(running) {
        paint.repaint();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    noise(g);
}

private void noise(Graphics g) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 800; i=i+10) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 800; j=j+10) {
            g.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
            g.fillRect(j, i, 10, 10);
        }
    }
    running = false;
}

}
```

So how would I implant the Perlin Noise algorithm to this code, while not having to install external libraries.
EDIT: I am not lazy, or something. I read my way through all possible Noise generations, I just don't completely understand how to immigrate the noise methods into the class.

Comment: 1) find/write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. We only help with #3. The other two are entirely YOUR responsibilty. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Include Stefan Gustavsson's simplex noise implementation as a separate class into your project, and use it.

Comment: You haven't specified your Perlin noise pre-conditions such as weights, nor have you shown your attempt and told us what problems you're having with your attempt. This suggests that you may be here too soon.

Comment: Don't override `paint()`. You should override `paintComponent()` instead, and its first executable statement should be `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Also a `while (true)` method shouldn't be used in a Swing application, especially one as you've written as you'll tie up your cpu rendering your computer a bit sluggish. If you want to repeat events, use a Swing Timer.

Comment: The paintCompnoent() method should not make any calculations that are used to draw your component - it should just draw it. Instead of what you are doing, you should double-buffer the painting - create an off-screen image and have a method that draws the new picture onto that image. Then your paintComponent() method should merely dump the image to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lucky, I recently did exactly this, heres my code:

```
BufferedImage tex;
float[] interpol;
int size;
float[] noise;
float[] workSet;
float r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2;
int octaves=4;
int octaveOffset=2;
public void init(int size)
{
    this.size=size;
    tex=new BufferedImage(size,size,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    interpol=new float[size];
    workSet=new float[size*size];
    noise=new float[size*size];
    float smult=(float) (Math.PI/size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        interpol[i]=(1+(float) Math.cos(i*smult))/2;
    }
    r1=255;
    g1=255;
    b1=255;
    r2=0;
    g2=0;
    b2=0;
}

public void generate()
{
    Random r=new Random();
    int[] pix=((DataBufferInt)(tex.getRaster().getDataBuffer())).getData();
    int totalSize=size*size;
    for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
    {
        noise[i]=0.5f;
    }
    float[] randoms=new float[(size+1)*(size+1)];
    int scale=size>>octaveOffset;
    float max=0.50f;
    for(int oct=0;oct<octaves;oct++)
    {
        int randsPerLine=size/scale+1;
        int rands=randsPerLine*randsPerLine;
        for(int i=0;i<rands;i++)
        {
            randoms[i]=max*(r.nextFloat()-0.5f);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
        {
            int y=(i/size)/scale;
            int suby=(i/size)%scale;
            int x=(i%size)/scale;
            int subx=(i%size)%scale;
            float intp=interpol[subx*(size/scale)];
            float colorA=randoms[y*randsPerLine+x]*intp+(1-intp)*randoms[y*randsPerLine+x+1];
            float colorB=randoms[(1+y)*randsPerLine+x]*intp+(1-intp)*randoms[(1+y)*randsPerLine+x+1];
            intp=interpol[suby*(size/scale)];
            workSet[i]=colorA*intp+(1-intp)*colorB;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
        {
            noise[i]+=workSet[i];
        }
        max/=2;
        scale/=2;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
    {
        int red=(int) (r1*noise[i]+r2*(1-noise[i]));
        int g=(int) (g1*noise[i]+g2*(1-noise[i]));
        int b=(int) (b1*noise[i]+b2*(1-noise[i]));
        pix[i]=(255<<24)+(red<<16)+(g<<8)+b;
    }
}
```

To draw it use `g.drawImage(tex,[your coordinates],null)`.
My code generates a square image `size` x `size` with a noisy mixture between two colors, currently black and white, this can be changed by modifying `r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2`. Play around with the `octaves` and the `octaveOffset` values to make the noise suit your needs.
I only tested this code with `size` being a power of 2 and while merging with your code I found out that it only works if `paint.init(1024)` and `paint.generate()` are called right at the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

Comment: Then pls press the accept answer button, this helps me and the others see that this topic is closed (and it also gives you reputation points).